# How to get correct return type depending on the generic argument from a generic function

Tags: typescript

How do I get the correct return type of a function, where the return type is depending on a generic argument?

```
function f1<T>(o: T) {
  return { a: o }
}

// I was hoping (n: number) would set T to number:
type T1 = typeof f1 extends (n: number) => infer R ? R : never // T1 is unknown
```

Answer (score 3):

TypeScript currently lacks support in the type system for most [higher kinded types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213), which is what you'd need to represent an operation on a generic function type.  So the short answer is "you can't do this, sorry".

---

Workarounds for this tend to involve manually specifying concrete types that you hope would be generic, or to convince the compiler to go through the required analysis by simulating some runtime effects.   It's hard to tell what your exact use case is from your example code, so the following workarounds are going to seem silly, but it's possible for your actual situation something like it can work.

For the former case of manually specifying things, your example code would turn into the relatively uninteresting:

```
type T1 = { a: number };
```

For the latter case of pretending to have runtime code, you could do something like this:

```
const t1 = true as false || f1(null! as number);
type T1 = typeof t1; // {a: number}
```

I've lied to the compiler that `true` has type `false`, meaning at runtime the expression `t1` will just [short-circuit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation) to `true` and `f1()` never gets invoked.  But at compile time the compiler thinks it is `false || f1(someNumber)` and thus expects the type of `t1` will be `{a: number}` as desired.

There was a [proposal](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6606) to allow you to use the type query operator `typeof` to work on any expression, and in a world where that was implemented you'd just write

```
type T1 = typeof f1(123);
```

and have no runtime code emitted whatsoever... but that proposal was declined, and so the above code is a [workaround for it](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6606#issuecomment-283584389).

---

Anyway, sorry I don't have a better answer for you. Hope this helped; good luck!

Comment: Thank for the explanation. I would love HKT in TS, since if I start defining a type for one generic function, then I need to define types for all of them in the execution path :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the reasoning but below should work fine for you

```
type f1<T> = (o: T) => { a: T }
type T1 = f1<number>
```

Typescript sees your f1 as a value not a type, thus it cannot create the T1 type before runtime.

Comment: My goal is to avoid defining explicit types for functions, since they already exists.

Comment: ...and that type isn't the type of the `f1` function anyway.  Since the real type of `f1` is a *non-generic* type representing a *generic* function (which operates on parameters of any type), whereas the type here is a *generic* type representing a *non-generic* function (which can only operate on a parameter of one type).   They are different.